# Domain Redirect with Masking

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, ssl, amazon-ec2

I've tried a few solutions but have not found any that work. So i'm sorry for what is probably a simple question.

I own a domain and want to point it at a github hosted website, but I want the URL in the browser to show my domain, not githubs url.

This is easy enough through my domain registrar, but I also want my domain to display as secure with an SSL cert. This is something my registrar can't offer through their masking service. So I have pointed my domain at my AWS EC2 Linux server, set up apache and have sorted the SSL to show as secure, but now I can't work out how to redirect my server to the github page (at all, nor) with masking.

To me the easiest solution is to edit the .htaccess file but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax. Or maybe i'm going about it the wrong way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^visibleDomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.github.com/accountname/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm also aware I could make some changes in my virtualHost but I really don't know how to proceed with that...

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: I only have 1 page that people will visit so I do not need to worry about mydomain.com/page1... /page2

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: I can't believe I missed this way of doing it. Much easier and far less time consuming. Thank you @MrWhite